# What's the worst that can happen when copyrighted materials are unintentionally shown on a live broadcast?

Tags: copyright

(I know little about law & copyrights and such so please feel free to correct any misuse of terms)

By "copyrighted materials", I mean stuff that automatically copyrighted like YouTube videos, as well as things like shots/clips from Disney movies & commercials and such.

By "live broadcast", I mean things like the news, live-streams (YouTube, Twitch, etc.), or anything else broadcasted live to the public.

By "unintentionally shown", I mean the copyrighted materials are shown in the live broadcast without the knowledge/consent of the one doing the broadcast (a pop-up commercial, accidentally opening the wrong video, someone in the background camera-bombing the broadcast, etc.).

Would the ones doing the live broadcast be protected against such unintentional showing of copyrighted materials? What's the worst that can happen?

Comment: How much of the copyrighted material did you "accidentally" show? For example, if you "accidentally" opened a movie on your broadcast, and then just let it play for the whole duration (e.g. 2 hours), that would be quite a different situation than if you accidentally opened a movie, played it only a few seconds, and then shut it off because you weren't sure if you are allowed to show that on a broadcast.

Comment: Let's say it's just a few seconds, up to maybe a couple of minutes.